# Firebase retrieving String as Long

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

why is firebase saving coordinates that i convert to string as Long?
I convert them like this:

```
update("latitude", latitude.toString(), "longitude", longitude.toString())
```

and i can see them as Strings in firebase

[image]

but when i retrieve them with a snapshotListener at first they come in as Long causing my app to crash then they turn into String. Here is the log

2021-04-08 14:05:29.089 21864-21864/com.crynet.overseer D/MYLOG: Its a Long

2021-04-08 14:05:29.503 21864-21864/com.crynet.overseer D/MYLOG: Its a Long

2021-04-08 14:05:30.314 21864-21864/com.crynet.overseer D/MYLOG: Its a String

2021-04-08 14:05:36.098 21864-21864/com.crynet.overseer D/MYLOG: Its a String

```
fb.collection("delivery").addSnapshotListener { collection, _ ->
        if(collection != null && !collection.isEmpty){
            map.clear()
            for (doc in collection){
                val lat = doc["latitude"] as String // Crash here
                val long = doc["longitude"] as String
                val trackingLatLng = LatLng(lat.toDouble(), long.toDouble())
                val options = MarkerOptions().position(trackingLatLng)
                map.addMarker(options)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nenhuma entrega está a ser feita de momento", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            map.clear()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe include the code you used to retrieve the value?

Comment: You need to provide the code that shows what is producing your log statements, and show how you are retrieving the coordinates from Firebase.  Clearly, firebase is saving them as a string, and you have a typing problem in your code.  So the question of your title is incorrect.

Comment: Sorry i really forgot to include the code.

Comment: What happens if you use the specific `DocumentSnapshot.getString()` method instead of the generic `DocumentSnapshot.get()`?

Comment: Also I am not sure why you are trying to store them as strings, when it looks like you convert them to doubles anyway when you read them?

Comment: its because firebase doesnt have double type data and it would give an error when trying to cast long as double. I read an advice somewhere that sometimes is better put everything in string in firebase which would be easy to cast and convert to other formats. And while writing this reply i manage to fix it by creating two variables `code` val newLat = lat.toString()
                    val newLong = long.toString() `code`  instead of casting them directly. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems that the problem is how the `addSnapshotListener` works. Before listen to the changes on server it checks locally first. That's why it triggers 2 times in my case.

To solve this you can either check if the snapshot is from server using `snapshot.metadata.isFromCache` or instead of casting the data to string directly save the data to another variable and then convert it to Double `.toDouble()` (in my case) when you are going to use the data.